# vue.js: How to dynamically change the value of a input field with the content from an other and still use value?

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-events

I have a firstName and a lastName input field and want to concat  both at the name input field, e.g.

```
<input id="firstName" :value"firstName" />
<input id="lastName" :value"lastName" />
<input id="name" :value"{{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}" readonly />
```

If I modify the value of the firstName or lastName field, the name input field should update the result.

I have a script which fill the `firstName` and the `lastName` fields with data from a GET request.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        data: {},
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
      },
    },
    methods: {
      getUser() {
        this.$axios({method: 'get', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get_user/',
      }).then(response => {
        this.data = response.data;
        this.firstName = this.data.firstName;
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I know that I cannot use `v-bind` and `v-model` together. But how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a computed property called `fullName` with getter/setter then bind it to the `v-model` :

```
computed: {
  fullName: {
     get(){
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
     },
     set(val){
   
     }
},
```

```
<input id="firstName" v-model="firstName" />
<input id="lastName"  v-model="lastName" />
<input id="name" v-model="fullName" readonly />
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have still the problem, that if I change the value for e.g. ``firstName``, the value from ``name`` doesn't change.

Comment: you should replace `:value` by `v-model` in other inputs

Comment: It works now. But I get the warning that val is unused. How could I make this more pretty?

Comment: you could do `set(_){` or `set(){`